# Determine whether the estimated value of over or underestimated

Tags: algebra-precalculus

To find an approximated value for $1.0125^{13}$ using the expansion of

$(\frac{x}{8} + 1)^{13} $ we substitute $x=0.1$ into the expansion up to and include the fourth term (for example) .

My question is how can we know whether the estimated value is over or underestimated without finding the exact value of ?

Comment: What are the signs of the missing terms in the binomial expansion?

Comment: The terms of $x^4$ and higher @Ted Shifrin

Comment: Yes, but @TedShifrin asked: "what are their signs?" It was a hint...